# How to authorize android app with firebase?

Tags: android, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have created an android/firebase app with email/password authentication. The app is related to game/play and scores. Than I created a user with email and password. The user can play game and raise its scores. The scores and game information is stored in firebase database. I than created a web app with same firebase database url. I got authenticated and from webapp and hacked the score to highest ever possible. Is there any way I can allow only android app user to access my database. I have provided security rules that only authorized user can modify its own score.

I want user should raise score by playing game on android only.

Comment: Yo can  refer this  link  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group               see this     Obtain a Client ID

Comment: genetarte api key wchich is for android apps and use this in manifest

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on API_KEY ? How to use it in manifest file ?

Comment: https://www.numetriclabz.com/integrate-google-drive-in-android-tutorial/                         Hoping you may get what you want